# Combining data from different rows into one variable

Tags: sas

I have a table as below:

```
 id  sprvsr phone name 
 2   123    5232  ali
 2   128    5458  ali
 3   145    7845  oya
 3   125    4785  oya
```

I would like to put same id and same name on one column and sprvsr and phone in one column together as below:

```
id  sprvsr     phone        name
 2  123-128    5232-5458    ali
 3  145-125    7845-4785    oya
```

edit question:
 have one more question- related this one.

i followed the way you showed me and works. Thank you! Another problem is for example:

```
 sprvsr      name
 5232-5458   ali
 5232-5458   ali
 5458-5232   ali
```

is there any way that i can make them in same order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need the variables in the same order, you'll need to use a temporary array and sort it.  This requires having some idea of how many rows you might have.  Also requires it to be sorted.  This is a bit more complicated than the previous solution (in a previous revision).

```
data have;
    input id sprvsr $ phone $ name $; 
    datalines;
2  123  5232  ali
2  128  5458  ali
3  145  7845  oya
3  125  4785  oya
4  128  5458  ali
4  123  5232  ali
;
run;

data want;
 array phones[99] $8 _temporary_;   *initialize these two to some reasonably high number;
 array sprvsrs[99] $3 _temporary_;
 length phone_all sprvsr_all $200;  *same;
 set have;
 by id;
 if first.id then do;               *for each id, start out clearing the arrays;
  call missing(of phones[*] sprvsrs[*]);
  _counter=0;
 end;
 _counter+1;                        *increment counter;
 phones[_counter]=phone;            *assign current phone/sprvsr to array elements;
 sprvsrs[_counter]=sprvsr;
 if last.id then do;                *now, create concatenated list and output;
  call sortc(of phones[*]);         *sort the lists;
  call sortc(of sprvsrs[*]);
  phone_all = catx('-',of phones[*]); *concatenate them together;
  sprvsr_all= catx('-',of sprvsrs[*]);
  output;
 end;
 drop phone sprvsr;
 rename 
    phone_all=phone
    sprvsr_all=sprvsr;    
run;
```

The construction `array[*]` means "All variables of that array".  So `catx('-',of phones[*])` means put all `phones` elements in the catx (fortunately, missing ones are ignored by `catx`).

Comment: thank you, it works exactly this code. but what  have originally doesn;t work because of my variables. I have 3 variables email-phone and id. even one of them doesn't work. the error as like this:ERROR: Variable supervisors_pidm has been defined as both character and numeric.
ERROR: The variable type of email is invalid in this context.
ERROR: The variable type of phone is invalid in this context.

Comment: The error about supervisors is that you can't mix character and numeric, that's basic SAS 101.  The other errors suggest that you're trying to use an array in a way you're not supposed to.  Is it on the lines where we use `of phones[*]`?

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to do that:

```
data have;
    input id sprvsr $ phone $ name $; 
    datalines;
2  123  5232  ali
2  128  5458  ali
3  145  7845  oya
3  125  4785  oya
;
run;
data want (drop=lag_sprvsr lag_phone);
    format id;
    length sprvsr $7 phone $9;
    set have;
    by id;
    lag_sprvsr=lag(sprvsr);
    lag_phone=lag(phone);
    if lag(id)=id then do;
        sprvsr=catx('-',lag_sprvsr,sprvsr);
        phone=catx('-',lag_phone,phone);
    end;
    if last.id then output;
run;
```

Just pay attention to the possible lenghts of the input variables and that of the concatenated string. The input dataset must be sorted by id.

The `catx()` function removes the leading and trailing blanks and concatenates with a delimiter.

Comment: @user3780068 Sounds like your supervisor variable is numeric, which isn't what you want.

Comment: thank you! i have this error now: ERROR: Variable supervisors_pidm has been defined as both character and numeric.

Comment: @user3780068 if sprvsr is numeric then transform it into a character string with `sprvsr2=put(sprvsr,8.);`

Comment: Joe that empty format statement doesn't strip the format, it simply doesn't overwrite it. It's only an inelegant way to have the id variable as first in the output dataset ;)

Comment: @DaBigNikoladze Hmm, okay.  Didn't recognize it was before `set`.